# Issue with matching

Tags: regex, perl

The following code below is trying to match a format like

`[a=>]b[->c][d:e]`

where `a=>`, `->`c, `d:e` are optional.

```
($reg =~ /^
     (?:([\w\/]+)=>)?       # (optional)
     (\w+)                  # (required)
     (?:->(\w+))?           # (optional)
     (\[\d+\]|\[\d+:\d+\])? # (optional)
     .$/x)
        or croak ("-E Invalid register format );
```

When I give the input as `sample=>STATUS` as `$reg value`, the last `S` of `STATUS` is getting truncated. Why?

Comment: Why is there a `.` in your regex?

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the . caused the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex symbol `.` just before your `$` line-end symbol captures "one thing" which in your case, seems to be the last letter `S`

This means that your regex is almost right, but that "one thing" needed to be satisfied by the regex, so the regex matcher rewound the required `(\w+)` pattern by one character to give the `.` its demanded character.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add, and escape, the square brackets

```
my $regex=qr{^
 (?:(\[[\w\/]+)=>\])?       # (optional)
 (\w+)                  # (required)
 (?:\[->(\w+)\])?           # (optional)
 (?:\[\w+\]|\[\w+:\w+\])? # (optional)
    }x;
```

Comment: From the sample datum, the brackets aren't actually there, they were just indicating the optional part